# Display draggable from div with display set to none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know if this is possible.  Is there any way to make a `div` element visible while the `div` is not displayed?  Specifically I'm using drag and drop items from a drop-down list, and once the list closes, they're invisible.  Ideas?

Comment: Why don't you replace them on the DOM (outside the list) while they are dragged?

Answer (score 1):

use the [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) drag samples, can help you for what you want.